# Reason: no suitable image found : Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib; start crashing in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, dylib, rpath

I have an existing iOS project written in Swift successfully running on iOS 8.4.1. I have compiled the project on Xcode 7 with some changes as per in Swift 2.0. It's running on Simulator. But when I start using device, Application start crashing at launch time 
/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib: mmap() error 1 at address=0x1002C0000, size=0x00214000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/89E98704-14A2-4341-B0A9-61F9DD639100/....../Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib.
I have tried all the suggestion from StackOverflow and other resources except Altering Apple Certificates.
Can anyone let me know what would be the issue and how can I overcome to this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Can anybody help me out to get solved it ?